# HTML5 time input - OS differences in Chrome

Tags: php, linux, windows, html, google-chrome

I know that time input is not functional in firefox.

However in Chrome under win7 it shows appropriately the time:minutes and Am/PM

```
<form id = "form5" form action = "./book.php" method="post" align='center'>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name='date'></br>
<input type="time" name="time"></br>
<input type="number" name="persons"></br>
     <input type = "submit" value = "Κράτηση">
</form>
```

in chrome under win10 the Am/Pm is missing.

Chrome in both OS is the same version.

Windows7: Version 45.0.2454.85 m 
Google Chrome is up to date.

Windows10:
Version 45.0.2454.85 m 
Google Chrome is up to date.

Linux Mint:
Version 44.0.2403.89 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17 (64-bit)

You can see the pictures below:

```
[![Windows10][2]][2]
[![Windows7][3]][3]
[![Linux Mint][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiPCO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk6KF.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2yEA.png
```

Comment: You have never mentioned what locale is used in those operating systems and under which locale Chrome operates. Using AM/PM with a 24 hour clock is useless. It appears that the locale you are using indicates that 24hr clock is used. Make sure you are using one and the same locale across your tests, because the data you provided at the moment isn't sufficient to help you move on with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to enter the tt at the time format.